# Swift - how to make inner property optional

Tags: swift, option-type

My question is in regards to optionals in swift. Let say i have the following defined already:

```
if let myCell = cell as? AECell {
    if !myCell.someView.hidden{
        //how do i use optional on someView, perhaps someView will not exists
    }
}
```

as you can see, what if someView is nil , how do i use an optional here to only execute the if statement if someView is not nil ..i tried the question mark:
`if !myCell.someView?.hidden` but its syntax is not correct

Comment: Is someView an optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if let myCell = cell as? AECell, let myView = myCell.someView where !myView.hidden {
    // This gets executed only if:
    // - cell is downcast-able to AECell (-> myCell)
    // - myCell.myView != nil (-> unwrapped)
    // - myView.hidden == false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let myCell = cell as? AECell, let someView = myCell.someView {
    // someView is unwrapped now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use optional chaining

```
if let myView = (cell as? AECell).someView {
    if !myView.hidden{
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `if let myView = (cell as? AECell)?.someView { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly, yes you can use optionals this way. The someView property of your cell must be defined as optional.

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var someView: AECell?
}
```

Then you can use the following syntax:

```
myCell.someView?.hidden = true
```

The behavior you're talking about is very much akin to Objective-C's nil messaging behavior. In Swift,you want to lean more towards confirming the existence of an object before manipulating it.

```
guard let myView = myCell.someView as? AECell else {
  // View is nil, deal with it however you need to.
  return
}
myView.hidden = false
```